# Python - '' string values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, string

I have about 1500 rows with no values for a column data that shows up when I run the code below:

```
df.loc[df['data'] == '']
```

How do I drop these 1500 rows?

I tried the code below:

```
df1 = df[df['data'].notna()]
df1
```

However, this does not seem to work as `''` is not a null value by the looks of it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `df[df['data'] != '']`?

Comment: Thanks. I tried this.  

df1 = df[df['data'] != '']]
df1

However, interestingly, I tried df.info() before running  the above code and then I tried df1.info(). Both show the same number of rows. I was expecting rows for df1 will be reduced since we removed rows with '' in data column. Is that correct?

Comment: Do you really have rows that are equal `''`? What does `(df['data'] == '').sum()` show? Perhaps you have `nan`'s?

Comment: Good idea. I ran (df['data'] == '').sum() and output was 1540. 

After that,  I ran (df1['data'] == '').sum() and output was 0.  

If that is case wonder why the number of rows are the same before and after I ran df1 = df[df['data'] != '']] df1 ?

Comment: @DarkKnight - Why doesnt Barmar's suggestion work?  plain and simple  `df = df[df['data'] != '']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should first replace empty values rows by `nan` and the drop these rows.

```
df['data' ] .replace("", nan_value, inplace=True)

df.dropna(subset = ["data"], inplace=True)
```